# Faraday disc voltage doubling

Tags: electromagnetism

imagine two cases, in both cases we have two faraday discs spinning on the same axis in the same direction but let's imagine each disc has it's B field lines pointing in the opposite direction so that in one disc the current goes from center to rim and in the other the current goes from rim back to center, 
in one case we simply electrically connect the rims together with a stationary connection and take the centers and connect them to brush contacts, in the  other case we add a stationary brush that connects the outer rims of the discs and still have the center brushes, tell me in which case there will be higher voltage?

I think that theoretically since even without sliding contacts attached there is a charge difference on a conducting disc that is spinning inside a homogeneous B field, I think that if the B field directions and current directions add up in series the effect should be the same on both discs or is it?

thanks.

Comment: " in one case we simply electrically connect the rims together with a stationary connection" I take it you mean stationary with respect to the discs, otherwise I can't see any difference in your two set-ups.

Comment: yes correct, stationary with respect to the discs, in other words we electrically solder or weld the conducting discs together while still maintaining that each disc has its homogeneous B field lines pointing in opposite directions so that the currents would add up.

Answer (score 0):

With the brush contacts joined by a wire stationary in the lab frame of reference there will be no induced emf in the wire and so the emf between brushes contacting the two axles will be, as you suggest, the sum of the emfs induced in the discs.

Things will be different when the edges of the disc are joined by a wire that rotates with the discs. To understand why, you need to think about the magnetic fields that you say run in opposite directions through the co-axial discs. Suppose the field goes from left to right through the right hand disc and from right to left through the left hand disc. Because magnetic field lines are continuous closed loops, there has to be a field coming (essentially) radially inwards in the region between the two discs, and this radial field will be cut by the rotating wire linking the discs. The emf generated in this wire will tend to cancel the sum of the emfs generated in the discs themselves.

Comment: ok, I understand but what if the opposite field lines come back not through the periphery or rim side of the discs but through the middle , say the rotor itself much like in a speaker magnet where all the field lines are concentrated in the airgap and then  they loop around through the middle not the outside? our physical electrical connection that rotates with the disc is at the rim so the field lines loop back through the middle, what would happen in this case?

Comment: I assume what I am asking is this - if I can make a setup where the field lines cut both rotating discs at opposite angles and the connecting part does not interfere with the b fields can I then have a setup that doesn't need any brushes or slipcontacts at all? because in the classical faraday disc example a load physically attached to the disc corotating with it has no curren t running through it because the current is only going in one direction at both the disc and load, but if I make this setup would it then be possible to connect the wires from both disc centers and have a load rotating?

Comment: Sorry but I can't properly understand your first comment. My first problem was not knowing what you mean by "the opposite field lines". Can you draw the field line configuration that you have in mind? I'm not much better with your second comment, either. But I don't think you can have a co-rotating wire connecting the disc rims that doesn't cut magnetic flux. As for connecting a load between the disc centres, so the load is co-rotating: I don't think that's a problem.

Comment: In the link is an image I made, brown lines are b field flux path, green is disc itself red dots are disc rim connection wires (subjected to no field lines) and green lines in the black rotor axis are meant as wires connected to the centers of the discs running through a hollow shaft and exiting after the b field and disc assemblies. I did not draw the magnets themselves just the field lines for simplicity, but much like a speaker magnet the field lines loop back around through the middle in this case through the rotor steel.

Comment: https://failiem.lv/u/chcvqjq3#_    this is the link to the picture

Comment: Thank you for the diagram. I understood that this was your set-up. But what you haven't done is to show the complete field lines, remembering that each is a continuous closed loop. Your field lines stop and start. Draw several $complete$ lines, and you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: well i'm imagining those lines in my head, well i forgot to say that inbetween the disc is a metal disc in order to guide the field lines back to the rotor and then to another disc located at the other side of the ferrite ring magnet , well as normally happens in a speaker magnet, just in this case imagine the copper disc is between the magnet's one side and the metal end plate forming essentially an airgap. the field in this gap is homogeneous I think, pardon I really can't see the problem here but I have a feeling something doesn't work in this concept, no matter what shape, without brushes

Comment: please explain :)

Comment: I've got it! You're returning the field lines along the axle. I now understand your reference to the loudspeaker magnet. Previously I thought that the lines must return outside the edges of the discs. But with the axial return path a problem now arises with the co-rotating load connected to the discs where they meet the axle. The load (or the wires to it) will cut flux returning to the inside of the axle. I've probably not explained myself very well, but I'm afraid I have to support your final (negative) conclusion.

Comment: but why would the b field lines cut the wires connecting to the load? first of all at the center of the discs there is very little current generation due to low angular speed , secondly I plan to make the rotor shaft hollow inside so that I can route the wires through the inside, the flux would travel through the steel so the hollow inside should pretty much be b field free?

Comment: You mean "the low speed"; the $angular$ speed is the same for all points on the disc. I think you're forgetting that to route the flux like this, the field will be very strong as it passes through the metal of the axle. Your load wires will cut this flux as they have to pass through the metal of the axles to reach its interior.

Comment: well yes the angular speed is the same I was thinking a different term, in other words more current is generated a the rim because of that part cutting more field lines for any given rotation than closer to center with the exact center point cutting no field lines whatsoever no matter how high the rpm I assume this is what I meant.

Comment: well the point where the wire enters the rotor shaft is a rather small opening do you think there will be much flux there ? because air has low permeability while steel has high so given the geometry I think little to no field lines should be present in that specific few mm hole which makes the wire pass to the hollow inside, but to be honest I'm not sure. ok but atleast in theory is it possible to make a rotor which has a wire that is cut by homogeneous b field lines and the wire can then be connected to a load that co-rotates with the rotor?

Comment: I can think of a few scenarios where such a setup could be made, like for example think of an aluminum soda can cut it in two halves and then you can make a magnet one for each halve reverse the field lines on the second half of the soda can and one could essentially join the can ends closest to the rotor middle together and the currents should add, the question is does this work at all? so far i'm having no luck, maybe because my setup is too simple and crude, just a bunch of small neodymium magnets and a wire passing over them

Comment: I'm still not convinced. I drew a diagram to help explain, but haven't a clue how to post it on this site. Another nitpick: it wouldn't be currents that add, but emfs. A bigger emf would certainly drive a bigger current through the load. Good luck!

Comment: maybe you can be so nice and upload the diagram on a image hosting site and then post the link here because as far as I am aware pictures can't be added here.

Comment: I wouldn't recognise an image-hosting site if it came out and shook me by the hand. I am an IT ignoramus. Sorry.